# TypeError: Cannot filter a non-Node argument; received False

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I am getting `TypeError: Cannot filter a non-Node argument; received False` on the second line of the following code (`query1 = ...`).

```py
def checkExits(EVname,EVmanufacturer,EVyear):
    query1 = EVModel.query(EVModel.name == EVname).fetch()
    query2 = EVModel.query(EVModel.manufacturer == EVmanufacturer).fetch()
    query3 = EVModel.query(EVModel.year == EVyear).fetch()
    query = ndb.get_multi(set(query1).intersection(query2.intersection(query3)))
    if len(query) == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: The first step to figure out what is going wrong is to know exactly *where* it is going wrong. Your error should contain a line number, what line is it? If it is the `ndb.get_multi()` line, that is doing quite a lot, so split those actions to find out where the problem is. Once you know where the problem is, it will be easier to see what the problem is.

Comment: The problem is in the line query1 = EVModel.query(EVModel.name == EVname).fetch()

Comment: What is the type of EVModel.name, EVname?